# Mirrored filesystem

Tags: linux, mirroring

I was thinking of mirroring a couple of directories across a number of (Linux) servers on my local network.

Google gave me [this article](https://serverfault.com/questions/266953/mirrored-filesystem-across-a-few-servers). But it is almost 10 years old. So, I image the state-of-the-art may have changed a bit.

I would appreciate an update.  Are there any new alternatives?

Comment: Do you need concurrent read/write activity, or the mirrored copies will be read only? Do you need block level or file level replication? What will the intended workload be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check on their git and release pages if they are still active ,

you should know **before** what you want to deploy  , *shared block storage* ( e.g. a  virtual disk ) like **ceph** or **drbd** , or a  *shared filesystem* , like [glusterFS](https://www.gluster.org/) / [globalFS](https://github.com/pacheco/GlobalFS)

### recommendation:  use **glusterfs** with bit-rot and 3+  machines :

- you can mount with a fuse or nfs ( small files , e.g. php are very slow over fuse )
- there is a fallback mechanism when a server fails
- it is well   documented and widely used
- it has advanced features like geo-replication and bit-rot and self-heal

Answer (score 2):

Obviously it depends on your requirements, but consider also [SyncThing](https://syncthing.net/).

You will have to manually indicate the private IP directions of the peers to your nodes as (currently, for updates see [here](https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing/issues/4277)) only the public IP gets automatically announced by SyncThing.
EDIT: Syncthing now announces the private IP also (in a secure way) as implemented [here](https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing/commit/b19b5c95d39ce5e25e1ee57a11ab00a9a23a62b3) so there's no need to manually specify it.